# looping Batch file from text input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using this code to run a batch file with arguments from a text file . but it is taking only last value from input file.

```
@echo off 

cd /d C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\Export


for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (Input.txt) do
 ( 
    set ITEMID=%%a
    set REV=%%b
    call :write %%a %%b
)

:write
echo ITEMID=%ITEMID%, REV=%REV%

cd /d C:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 8.5\UGMANAGER
ug_export -part=%ITEMID% -rev=%REV% -u=arvind -p=asfa@p -role=dba -export_dir=C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\Export

exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `exit /B` command after the closing `)` to not fall into the `:write` subroutine unintentionally after the main program (`for` loop) has finished.
The opening `(` of the `for` body needs to be in the same line as the `do` keyword.

You do not need to set `ITEMID` and `REV` as you are passing `%%a` and `%%b` to your subroutine.
Within `:write` use `%1` to access the first parameter and `%2` for the second one.

This should work:

```
@echo off 

pushd "C:\Program Files\Siemens\NX 8.5\UGMANAGER"
for /f "usebackq eol=; tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (
    "C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\Export\Input.txt"
) do (
    call :write "%%~a" "%%~b"
)
popd
exit /B

:write
echo ITEMID="%~1", REV="%~2"

ug_export -part="%~1" -rev="%~2" -u=arvind -p=asfa@p -role=dba -export_dir=C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\Export

exit /B 0
```

If the tool `ug_export` does not support `-part` and `-rev` arguments to be quoted, write `ug_export -part=%~1 -rev=%~2 ...` instead.

I avoided changing to the directory path `ug_export` for every execution of `:write` by changing to it once in the main section (using `pushd` and `popd`).

**Hint:** For debugging it is *very* helpful to remove `@echo off` temporarily...

Comment: I am getting this error and calling batch file is not executing ...   "The system cannot find the batch label specified - write"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the content of `Input.txt`? I just fixed an issue concerning arguments `%%a` and `%%b` for the case they contain spaces...

Comment: Input are as below:                                                                   000112998,A

Comment: I don't get the error you described (I commented out the `ug_export` line for testing as I don't have that tool); I suggest to try again with the most recent [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32270715/3); perhaps the error does not appear during the first `for` iteration; you should also check whether or not `ug_export` supports quoted arguments as described in my answer...